# ¿Que son los parametros (Object sender, EventArgs e) en los eventos? - C#

Tags: c#

Estaba repasando el tema de eventos en C#, busque algunos ejemplos y por lo general veo ejemplos en donde aparecen los siguiente campos (object sender , EventArgs e) , este es un codigo que entiendo relacionado al tema eventos y no lleva los campos (object sender,eventargs e) aclro ademas que entiendo el tema de delegados y todo este fragmento de codigo, mi problema es con el otro formato.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Evento e = new Evento();
        //Se crea el evento y asigna el metodo estatico al evento, 
        e.evento += OnEvento;
        //hace lo mismo que la primera pero con el EventHandler, ambas funcionan igual
        e.evento += new Evento.EventHandler(OnEvento);

        e.OnEvento("HolaMundo");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void OnEvento(String s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public class Evento
    {
        public delegate void EventHandler(String s);

        public event EventHandler evento;

        public void OnEvento(String s)
        {
            if (evento != null)
                evento(s);
        }
    }

}
```

pero no puedo entender muy bien el otro formato de sintaxis de evento, es decir segun lei sender hace referencia a la clase que disparo el evento y eventargs a los campos, pero no puedo entenderlo bien... por ejemplo: si yo tuviera mas de un parametro ,¿tendria que poner algo como (object sender,eventsargs A , eventargs B)?

Me ayudaria que me explicaran en alguncodigo sencillo que son estos 2 campos y por que es tan necesario sender.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En los manejadores de eventos suele haber dos parámetros de entrada: `object sender` y `EventArgs e`.

Vamos a fijarnos en el manejador de un evento `ButtonClick`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Aquí, `sender` lo que hace referencia es al objeto que disparó el evento. Es decir, en este caso contendrá la instancia del botón que disparó el evento `Click`.

En cuanto a [`EventArgs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.eventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2), esta es una clase genérica para el paso de información del evento. En el caso de un evento `Click` de un botón, realmente no contiene nada ya que se pasa únicamente la clase genérica. Pero vamos a fijarnos en otro evento, por ejemplo `MouseClick`:

```
private void Button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

Como ves, en este caso no se pasa la clase genérica `EventArgs`, si no [`MouseEventArgs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2). La firma de esta clase es la siguiente:

```
public class MouseEventArgs : EventArgs
```

Es decir, hereda de `EventArgs` y contiene varias propiedades que dan información del evento: `Button`, `Clicks`, `Delta`, `Location`, `X` e `Y`.

Esto responde a tu pregunta

> si yo tuviera mas de un parametro ,¿tendria que poner algo como (object sender,eventsargs A , eventargs B)?

No. Lo que debes hacer es crear una clase que herede de `EventArgs`, con las propiedades que necesites crear para pasar la información que te interese, y la firma de tu `EventHandler` sería algo como

```
private void evento(object sender, MiEventoEventsArgs e)
```

y accederías a las propiedades con `e.MiPropiedad1`,`e.MiPropiedad2`, etc..

Espero haberme sabido explicar bien, si tienes alguna duda o no entiendes algo no dudes en comentarmelo y trataré de mejorar mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El evento es un tipo de delegado, en el caso de los OnClick y demás eventos esta presente el `sender` porque son declarados así

```
public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
```

[code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/RoutedEventArgs.cs,af107ecb60427a17) linea 431